# Adding Child items to DevExpress XtraNavBar

Tags: navigation, devexpress

I am using the XtraNavBar from DevExpress and I would like to figure out how to add a child item to an existing item.

I have added Groups and Items to those Groups but I have been unable to figure out how to add child items to the Items.

Has anyone else done this?  Can it be done either through code or any other way?

---

*(for reference)*

[Product Page](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/NavBar/)

[Feature Page](http://www.devexpress.com/Help/?document=xtranavbar/customdocument4870.htm)

---

### Edit

I found **ONE** way to do this, [HERE](http://www.devexpress.com/Help/?document=xtranavbar/customdocument4870.htm), but I was hoping there was another way, I guess.  Building a separate control (*TreeView I'd guess*) and embedding it was not the answer I was **HOPING** for.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the XtraNavBar as a list of views where a NavBarGroup represents a view. That's why you cannot add child to a group.

In one of our applications, we are using this control. Each NavBarGroup has a container which contains a more sophisticated control.

Here a simple example how we do it:

```
//Create the group control container
NavBarGroupControlContainer groupContainer = new NavBarGroupControlContainer();
NavBarGroup group = new NavBarGroup("GroupName");
group.SmallImage  = new Icon("YourIcon.ico");
group.GroupStyle  = NavBarGroupStyle.ControlContainer;

m_navBar.Controls.Add(groupContainer);
group.ControlContainer = groupContainer;
group.Visible = true;

customControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
groupContainer.Controls.Add(customControl);
```

Comment: Very Nice! Thank you!  Out of curiosity, what kind of controls have you embedded in a NavBar?

Comment: @Refracted Paladin: ImageListBoxControl, TreeList, Our own custom control. Since you can add any control in the group contrainer, the possibilities are infinite.

Comment: You also need: `m_navBar.Groups.Add(group);` to actually make it visible.